# How to create a function in which a box moves in accordance with 2 user inputs (direction and # of pixels to move)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's what I have so far:

The following is my CSS for the box:

```
  p
    {
       width: 100px;
       padding: 25px;
       border: 25px solid red;
       margin: 25px;
       position: fixed;
       top: 100px;
    }
```

And here is the JavaScript and HTML I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Box Mover</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet"; style="text/css"; href="style.css">
    </head>

    <script>
       function initialize()
       {
            var positionBox = document.getElementById("positionBox");
            positionBox = addEventListener("click", moveBox);

       }

       function moveBox()
       {
            var positionBox = document.getElementById("positionBox");
            positionBox.style.position = "absolute";
       }
    </script>


    <body>
        <p>This is a box.</p>

        <form>
            Number of pixels to move:
            <input id="numPixels">
            <br>
            <br>
            Direction to move:
            <select id="directionSelection">
                <option>Up</option>
                <option>Down</option>
                <option>Left</option>
                <option>Right</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input id="positionBox" type="button" value="Move Box">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The part I am stumped on is how I can get my positionBox button to interact with my directionSelection drop-down menu and numPixels within my JavaScript.  Could someone help me out here?

In my class yesterday, my prof showed us an example of getting a button to move with hard-coded parameters, but now I need to do that with a box, making it move in the direction the user specifies, along with the number of pixels to move.  I could also post that example code if it could be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The part I am stumped on is how I can get my positionBox button to interact with my directionSelection drop-down menu and numPixels within my JavaScript

In your `moveBox` function, use `document.getElementById("numPixels").value` and `document.getElementById("directionSelection").value` to get the number of pixels and the direction to move.

> showed us an example of getting a button to move with hard-coded parameters, but now I need to do that with a box

To be able to move the box from your `moveBox` function, you will need to add an `id` attr to the `<p>This is a box.</p>` element so that you can select it with `var box = document.getElementById("myBox");`. Then, apply the values to `box.style.top` and `box.style.left` to move the box around instead of applying the values to the `positionBox`.

Comment: Is this the right idea so far?

`function moveBox()
       {
            var positionBox = document.getElementById("positionBox");
            positionBox.style.position = "absolute";
            var numPixels = document.getElementById("numPixels").value;
            var directionSelection = document.getElementById("directionSelection").value;
            var box = document.getElementById("myBox");
       } `

Comment: Yes. Now, just do something with the `numPixels` and `directionSelection` values.

Comment: I've figured it out now!  I just needed to incorporate various if statements to determine what direction was selected from the drop-down box, and then add or subtract the number of pixels specified depending if it's going left, right, up, or down.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @DanCzarnecki No problem. If you are finished with this question and this answer was helpful then please click the checkmark next to it to accept it. Thanks.